# How to custom LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder in netty 4.0.25 final

Tags: java, netty

I am a newbie netty.
i have message

- (Header)(Length)(Type)(MessageBody) with size
- <4bytes><4bytes><4bytes><...> - The Length includes the Type and
  MessageBody.

i want get header and type of message, how to custom LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder in netty 4.0.25 final?
I reference link: [Buffer Returned from LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352450/buffer-returned-from-lengthfieldbasedframedecoder-too-small) but it's netty 3.xx.

Answer (score 2):

Why customise LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder at all? Set

- maxFrameLength to the largest message you'll accept
- lengthFieldOffset = 4
- lengthFieldLength = 4
- lengthAdjustment = 0
- initialBytesToStrip = 0

Then the next decoder upstream will receive a ChannelBuffer containing the entire message, which you can parse and process how you like.

Comment: Why 4 bytes? This really depends on his message size. 4 Bytes could be very wasteful depending on his max packet size.

Comment: @Underbalanced because the OP said it is 4 bytes in the question